# Record sound in good quality?

Tags: .net, vb.net, audio, audio-recording

How I can record sound from my PC in GOOD quality? (A Microsoft Wav File 16 bit 44 khz or encoding mp3 in real time).

Not a problem for me if I can use a FREE and DOCUMENTED library to record audio, but I can't find any.

I found **mciSendString** on Google but this is like recording audio quality from phones of the 90's...:

```
mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0)
mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0)
```

Comment: You want to record sound that is playing in your environment or sound that is playing on your PC (so you could record without hearing it)?

Comment: Here are no other methods you might be interested in:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12574/Simple-audio-recording-program or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx?

Comment: @djerry thanks for comment and the edit, I want to record sound that is playing in my environment, is impossible to not exist other methods cause then how all the recording programs do the work? maybe not with native classes but sure with recording libraries...  I think that but I'm total newbie in audio-recording.

Comment: In what environment are you working? Depensing on that, you can take a look at the Media Capture API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx

Comment: Windows 7, but i'm looking for a compatible method for XP/Vista/7/8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28717/discussion-between-djerry-and-elektro-hacker)

Comment: @ElektroHacker what microphone are you using?  If you want something that sounds like it came out of a studio you will need a good quality microphone... the little tin button inside a webcam won't do.

Comment: @J I don't use any microphone, I only said the quality of my code example is recording the audio in the same quality as a microphone qualiy (bad bad quality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used http://www.portaudio.com/ and been happy with it.  Plus, it's cross-platform and you can specify bit-depth, sample-rate, etc. when opening devices for recording.  For exporting audio data to files, I like to use http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/.

If you're strictly using Windows, however, you might just use the waveIn* functions (see here to get started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743847(v=vs.85).aspx)

Note that theses solutions are not necessarily .NET specific, but utilize native code.

Comment: Thanks for answer but This is a .NET enviroment question then of course my OS need to be Windows to programming in Framework, I looked the PortAudio site which don't have any Windows compatibility, so I looked libsnd which is for Linux too... have a version for Windows but with a pair of C/C++ projects that can't understand, any documentation on google for this lib on .NET. So I can only choose the third option, thankyou for the info.

Comment: PortAudio and libsnd both can run on Windows.  You are right that they *can* run on Linux, but both are cross-platform libraries.

Comment: ouch, but I've downloaded portaudio and it needs to compile before on Linux, or I'm wrong?

Comment: No, you can compile it on Windows, but if you're not familiar with C/C++, then maybe you should give this a go since you are targeting .NET: https://code.google.com/p/portaudiosharp/.  Under "Downloads", try PortAudioSharp-bin-release-0.19.3.zip ...